# Искажение слов при заимствовании

Tags: орфография, лексика, фонетика, заимствования

Я заметил, что при заимствовании английских слов происходит их (порой довольно существенное) искажение. В большинстве случаев искажения бывают двух видов:

1. Изменение ударения:

   - «facet»: исходно *фа́сет*, но стало *фасе́т*;
   - «Florida»: исходно *Фло́рида*, но стало *Флори́да*.
2. Изменение произношения:

   - «xerox»: исходно *зирокс*, но стало *ксерокс*. Что, впрочем, не помешало перевести *Xena* как «Зена» (которая королева воинов);
   - «pattern»: исходно *пэттерн*, но стало *паттерн*.

В чём причина подобного явления?

Объяснение удобством произношения кажется маловероятным, поскольку исходные варианты органично вписываются в фонетическую систему русского языка.

---

Кстати, эта проблема касается не только английского языка. Насколько мне известно, заимствования из немецкого тоже подвержены подобной проблеме. Пара примеров:

- **Röntgen** (IPA: /ˈɹɛnt.ɡən/) — близко к [*р’о́нтг’эн*], то есть «Рёнтген». Однако традиционно это имя пишут через «е» с переносом ударения.
- **Einstein** (IPA: /ˈaɪnstaɪn/) — близко к [*а́йнстайн*], то есть «Айнстайн». Но нам больше известен вариант «Эйнштейн».

Comment: "Па́ттерн" в моих кругах общения употребляют с исходным ударением. Может, потому что в моём случае те, кто это слово употребляет, знают английский язык :\

Comment: @D-side, возможно. Но это слово используется ведь не только в программировании. *Паттерн поведения*, например.

Comment: Не самый авторитетный источник, но [в Википедии "паттерн"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD) тоже с ударением на А.

Comment: В русском языке вообще немецкий диффтонг `ei` чаще приживается, как ей/эй, чем ай... Думаю тут дело в письменности, читали "как пишется"

Comment: Даже не зирокс, а скорее зиэр[э/а]кс, `/ˈzɪərɒks/ `. В русском языке вроде бы нет таких звуков.

Comment: @D-side, вы правы. Заменил пример на более удачный (спасибо VladimirGamalian [за подсказку](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36935186#36935186)).

Comment: Во Флорида как раз изначальное ударение на *и*, как в испанском, но сейчас под влиянием английского смещается на *о*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Искажения бывают по разным причинам:

1. Удобство произношения
2. Благозвучность
3. Влияние уже существующих слов
4. Незнание произношения в языке откуда заимствовано
5. Устоявшаяся традиция произношения определённых звуков и букв
6. Особенности русской графики и фонетики

В ваших примерах искажения возникают по последним трём причинам. Люди видят написано *Xerox*, а по-английски, немецки французски оно написано непонятно, поэтому читают по-латински (в случае с Зеной переводчики слышали аудио). Дифтонг **ei** с немецкого ещё с XVIII в. переводили на русский как **эй** (на немецком он среднее между а и э), а в случае с Рентгеном, Черчилем и Тэтчер, проблема в том, что в русском языке ё всегда ударная и обозначает мягкость предшествующего согласного, а в этих фамилиях ударение падает на другой слог, так что искажений было бы не избежать в любом случае.

Comment: Подробнее в ответе Грамоты.ру: 
http://learning-russian.gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_10_zaimst